# Lock an NFC tag to specific device?

Tags: java, android, security, nfc

Is it possible to lock an NFC tag in such a way that only a specific device can read from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it this way - in order for an NFC tag to distinguish between devices it first must be powered on. In order for a tag to be powered on, it needs to connect to a device. While "connect" is used a bit loosely here, at some point the tag needs to power on with the device.

Then, for the tag to have the means to prohibit devices from accessing its own data, it must identify the device somehow.

Currently no tags natively support these operations, and there is no standardised way of identifying specific devices.

Some tags do however support authentication with passwords, so maybe you should look into that.

Answer (score 1):

No, not as I'm aware of. NFC tags are not "smart" they can't decide over their own faith in the sense that who is allowed to read them.

But one way is to encrypt the data on the NFC tag and only keep the random key in the device that should be allowed access.